# How to re-order elements in a forEach call JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a html page with 3paragraphs and a button. In my JavaScript file, I created a function that adds 3 new paragraphs to the page each time I hit the button. These 3 new paragraphs should be copies of the existing ones, but each time be added in a randomised order.
Here is my function

```
const body = document.querySelector("#body");
const paragraphs = document.querySelector(".paragraph");
const btnHitMe = document.querySelector("#btn");

const addParagraphs = () => {
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(paragraphs, (el) => {
    
    const node = document.createElement("P");
    node.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;

    body.insertBefore(node, btnHitMe);

  });

}
```

The above code adds the paragraphs successfully.
My problem is how do I add these paragraphs in randomised order each time I hit the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `querySelector` does return only the 1st selected element.

Use `querySelectorAll` instead.

---

Secondly, Choose [one of shuffle algorithms mentioned in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/747579), then use it to shuffle `paragraphs` before looping over it.

---

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll(".paragraph"); // <- here
// .... 
  // shuffle function should be added from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/747579
  let randomizedParagraphs = shuffle(Array.prototype.slice.call(paragraphs)) // <-- here
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(randomizedParagraphs, (el) => { // <- here
//....
```